# Select a td from a tr which has the text matching and add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to web development. I have a table with a simple structure. Here, I want to find a tr containing a  `td` value `"abc"` and then add the class to that tr. I am able to add it to `td` but not to the tr . Please help.

`var container = document.querySelector("[id^='taTextElement']").id`;

```
var match = "Duration";
$('#'+container +' ' +'table tr').each(function() { }
```

One more thing here, table Id is also there.So, can anyone please help me with this ?

Here I have not added the ID part.

HTML -

```
<table border="1"> <tbody><tr><td> Designation :</td><td></td></tr><tr><td> Duration :</td><td>JANUARY 2015 to APRIL 2015</td></tr><tr><td> Technologies : </td><td>Tritium, Sublime Text, Firefox, Chrome, Action Script, HTML, CSS, Javascript, jQuery</td></tr><tr><td> Team Size: </td><td></td></tr><tr><td> URl : </td><td></td></tr><tr><td> Employer :</td><td></td></tr><tr><td> Client : </td><td></td></tr><tr><td> Domain : </td><td></td></tr><tr><td> Roles and responsibility : </td><td>Contribution:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Using Client API in this project had to fix many issues while mobilizing the desktop site  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Code validation, Unit testing, Manual testing done for every task. &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td> Description: </td><td>Description:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; As a part of this project we were mobilize the desktop websites.

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Add your html also

Comment: It would really help if you add your HTML too.

Comment: Try: `$('#'+container +' ' +'table tr:has(td:contains("abc"))')`

Comment: Added the html in the question

Comment: Can you please tell me what will be the selection if it has also the table ID

Comment: Use $('some query').parent()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:contains` selector like:

```js
$(function() {
  var toSearch = "Island"; /* Word to seach */
  $("#table1 td:contains(" + toSearch + ")").parent().addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

For exact search, you can use `filter`

You can use:

```
var toSearch = "Francisco Chang"; /* Word to seach */
$("#table1 td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text().trim() === toSearch }).parent().addClass('selected');
```

Comment: I have the div ID as well and the table has  a ID as well

Comment: @GaneshKaspate This is an example to use the `:contains` selector. If you have a table ID, you can also use that. What is table id?

Comment: table1 is the ID of table

Comment: Hey, this is great. Currently, on button this action happens. But what is happening is when I click that button then I dont get any table but when I second time click I get all the tables . Can you tell me the reason behind this

Comment: There might be a problem with your btn. Please make a jsfiddle.com for me to check the code

Comment: Okay. I will check. And one more thing like, contains method is like contains test but if I want to check for the exact match then >

Comment: I added a code for exact search. You cant use `contains` for exact

Comment: Okay thanks, And Also I can use If I want to search for a paragraph with the Id and has text matching using contains

Comment: Yes, you can use `contains` for `<p>`

Comment: Het @Eddie If you have some time then can you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49152036/highlight-a-text-from-html-document-from-different-tags/49156119?noredirect=1#comment85337380_49156119

Comment: Okay. Ill try later :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to select the td, you can use  the `jQuery.parent ()` method to get the `tr` and add the class.

So in your `.each function`

```
var tds = $(this).children ().filter (function(){return $(this).text () == 'abc';});
tds.each (function (){
  $(this).addClass (yourClass) ; 
  $(this).parent ().addClass (trClass);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As a comparison, you can do this in POJS by:

1. Getting the cells in the table as an array (or NodeList with *forEach*, see below)
2. Loop over the cells and add a 'highlight' class to rows that contain matching text

Since most browsers now implement *forEach* on NodeLists, you can call it on the NodeList returned by *querySelectorAll*. Otherwise, you may need to convert the NodeList to an array first (e.g. use *Array.from(NodeList)*).

```js
function highlighTRWithText(text) {
  document.querySelectorAll('#table0 td')
    .forEach(cell => { 
      if (cell.textContent.indexOf(text) > -1) cell.parentNode.classList.add('highlight');
    });
}

window.onload = function(){
  highlighTRWithText('Team Size');
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="table0" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> Designation :</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Duration :</td>
      <td>JANUARY 2015 to APRIL 2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Technologies : </td>
      <td>Tritium, Sublime Text, Firefox, Chrome, Action Script, HTML, CSS, Javascript, jQuery</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Team Size: </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> URl : </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Employer :</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Client : </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Domain : </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Roles and responsibility : </td>
      <td>Contribution:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Using Client API in this project had to fix many issues while mobilizing the desktop site &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Code validation, Unit testing, Manual testing
        done for every task. &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Description: </td>
      <td>Description:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; As a part of this project we were mobilize the desktop websites. &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: will this only find the first match, or all matches?

Comment: @klewis—all of them.